# Privilégio de adm (Windows 7)

Tags: windows

O firewall do trabalho está me travando, não consigo ver os videos de programação do coursera... em resumo, não tenho privilégio de adm.

Gostaria de sugestões sobre como resolver esse problema...

Abcs.

Answer (score 1):

O Windows 7, por padrão, vem com a conta do Administrador (com privilégios totais) desativado por uma questão de segurança e mesmo que você procure-a na relação de usuários do sistema você não vai encontrá-la.

Todo usuário com perfil do “tipo” administrador, tem privilégios suficiente para fazer o que quiser no sistema, mas suponhamos que essa conta padrão sofra alguma avaria na pasta de configurações ou você tenha a necessidade de usar uma conta de administrador sobressalente, como ativar a conta (oculta) Administrador?

A dica é simples, mas pode ser muito útil, e vale lembrar que essa conta deve estar com senha para evitar que outro usuário use-a para fins que possam danificar o sistema operacional.

Abra o menu iniciar e escreva **cmd** como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Clique com o botão direito e selecione Executar como administrador.]

Clique com o botão direito e selecione:

**Executar como administrador.**

E no terminal, digite:

```
NET USER ADMINISTRADOR /   ACTIVE:YES
```

Dê enter e faça LOGOFF e deverá aparecer as duas contas.

Fonte: Profissionais TI.

Isso deve  ajudar.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Faça como está na resposta.

Comment: Quando tento executar como adm ele me impede e solicita o usuário e senha do administrado...@IsraelSousa

Comment: A conta de administrador da sua máquina deve ter senha.

Comment: é exatamente esse o problema...

Comment: Você vai precisar remover a senha do Windows usando uma distribuição Linux.

Comment: consegue me explicar?

Comment: Siga esse tutorial, ele apenas vai trocar a senha do Administrador.

Faça o mesmo processo para acessar o **cmd** pelo menu iniciar, ao chegar no prompt de comando, digite **net user**, irá aparecer o nome de todas as contas disponíveis no seu sistema.

Depois digite net user "Administrador" * e insira uma nova senha para a conta do administrador.

Comment: ta.... ao inserir o comando net user "administrador" visualizo o administrador, mas como altero sua senha? @IsraelSousa

Comment: Você esqueceu de colocar o asterisco depois do... "Administrador".

Assim:

net user "Administrador" *

Comment: consegui até chegar a troca da senha, entretanto deu "erro de sistema 5 - Acesso Negado"

Comment: Você tem que executar o **cmd** como administrador assim como mostrado na imagem da resposta.

Comment: Então... @IsraelSousa, eu não consigo acessar o cmd como adm... quando tento, ele imediatamente abre uma janela pedindo usuário e senha...

Comment: Você está utilizando a conta do **Convidado**?

Comment: Sim...@IsraelSousa

Comment: Tente reiniciar o computador apertando a tecla **F8** até aparecer uma tela preta do Windows, depois entre em **Modo seguro com rede**.

Se isto não der certo, você terá que remover a senha do Windows utilizando uma distribuição **Linux** ou um programa de boot específico.

Ex.: **Ophcrack**

Na internet você encontra algum tutorial acerca de como remover a senha do Windows 7 utilizando esse programa ou qualquer distribuição **Linux**.